# How to format Date that stores in Map<String,Object> in spring rest as UTC in deserialization?

Tags: java, spring, date, format, deserialization

I have a user class that has a field with Map<String,Object> type.

```
public class User {
private Map<String,Object> customFields;
... other fields 
}
```

When I call the end point that retrieves User Object from database, I see the birth date in long milliseconds and In database the format is as same as endpoint E.G, 1641135600000,.
How can I format the birth date in spring rest deserialization? E.G, 2020-01-05.
Imagine that I call localhost:8080/users/23 I'll get:

```
{
"id":23,
"customFields":{
"birthdate":1641135600000,
...}
}
```

I'm using mongo Db 4 for this project.
When I query the db, I'll get the same result.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more about this problem?

Comment: @Navin Kumar, I added more details. If you have specific details in your mind, please comment down I'll add more.